# Accessing and manipulating Google Sheets in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm attempting to use Google Sheets as a back-end for an iOS app. The spreadsheets in question are private, so will require Oauth 2.0 for interactions.

So far I have come across three different ways to access spreadsheet data, but I'm not sure which one is the right one.

- [GData library](https://github.com/google/gdata-objectivec-client)
- [Google API Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client)
- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/?hl=en)

Has anyone here found success with any of these options, and if so how?

Comment: Your question is actually multiple questions, some technical, some philosophical (ranty, even), so where would an answerer start? I suggest you [edit] it to focus on a solution avenue you want to pursue, otherwise it's unlikely to get you the help you need.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote this through frustration so it's definitely not focused. I'll edit it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than any of the options you've listed, you should be looking at the 
[Apps Script Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/), which is a supported component of the Google Apps Script environment. It was [introduced just over a month ago](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.ca/2015/09/run-apps-script-code-from-anywhere.html), in response to the growing demand for ubiquitous access to Google Apps.

As for the "how" - the [Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/target-script) should get you started.

Comment: Thank you. The Apps Script Execution API was one of the routes I attempted (I should have listed it rather then just the generic Apps Script page). It was successful in accessing folders within Google Drive.


It requires an extra layer of code essentially though, since there needs to be a script running in the cloud that is then called by the iOS app. This is why I was hoping there was a different solution that would work better.


Thanks though. I'll go with this solution instead.